# Multiple tables or one mega-table in SQL?

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL. I am trying to design an online file storage system. The actual file storage will be taken care of separately - I just want to use MySQL to make a database of file metadata (eg. file names, file sizes, file types, permissions, etc.). My system will need to handle up to 1000 users, who will each be able to store up to 1000 files.

I want to create a database of file records. Is is best to create one file-record table per user, and then make another table which lists the users and references the corresponding tables? Or should I make one big table of file records, and then simply include a column called "user"?

I guess the advantage of the multiple table approach is that I never have to step through 1,000,000 records. But I don't know much about mySQL, so I don't know if 1,000,000 records is a lot to work through or not.

Comment: better an integer column called 'userid' and a separate table containing the users' details

Comment: @Ord:  I think we have some confusion over your terminology: "one file-record table per user"...some of us have interpreted this as meaning one table per user, and others have interpreted it as one record per user.  Perhaps you want to clarify your question.

Comment: I meant one table per user. From the comments I have received, it seems pretty obvious that this is the wrong way to go!

Comment: @Ord - yes absolutely, one table per user is definitely the wrong way to go.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the advice. I now recognize that one table per user is absolutely out of the question. I think I will opt for one table of file records, and one table of user records. The file records table will have a field for userid to link each file to the correct user. I recognize the benefits of using the many-to-many solution Shef proposed, but I don't think this will be necessary for my application. Thanks all!

Comment: @Ord: glad you finally got the answer you needed.  Sounds like that will work nicely for you; good luck!

Comment: He clearly states "one file-record *table* per user"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make one big table of file records, and simply include a column called "user".  You do NOT create separate tables that store the exact same information.

**EDIT:**  You should create one big table with a column that stores a reference to the user.  It has been suggested that userid would be an appropriate name, but you can call it whatever you like.  The actual user information would need to be in a separate table (linked by this key).

Comment: Yeah, and how will he store the `user` there? `username` and `name` and `surname` and who knows what... So don't shoot yourself on the foot with "You do NOT create separate tables that store the exact same information.", because you are advising him to do JUST that.

Comment: @Alnitak:  Agreed...I was just so appalled at the thought of a thousand user tables...and an answer that actually recommended that (but I think he misread something), that I just fired of the post quickly

Comment: @Gerrat: What happens if he wants to share one file for two users? I would like to know what you would come up with...

Comment: @Shef - he was only quoting the (correct) choice out of the two choices that the OP suggested.

Comment: @Alnitak: The OP also suggested he is new to MySQL, so don't feed him this kind of design, because he will live nightmares at some point in time.

Comment: So I should have a big table of file records, and each record should have a userid field - this will reference a row in a second table, which stores all of the information about a user. Is that correct?

Comment: @Ord: That is correct.  If you wanted to have multiple users each sharing the same file, then you'd need a third table to go between these two tables (as Shef has suggested).  ...from your description, this didn't sound necessary though.

Comment: @Shef huh?  What design!?  You're the one that proposed an unnecessary many->many link between files and users...

Comment: @Alnitak: That's a many to many solution, so he won't pollute the files table, and he will get a lightning speed out of that table's read. What would you do if he wanted to share the files... that's a million dollars question?

Comment: Someone just missed the normalization rules, out of this suggestion. :)

Comment: @Alnitak: History is just golden, just that..., a good solution is another thing. Hey, this is not the end of the world, he will come back to that decision when he will wake up in the middle of the night because his paying customers would love to report a service failure...

Answer (score 5):

I'd go for all the file records in one table.  1 million records isn't really all that big a deal for MySQL - I've used tables with 100x more records than that without any problem.

Just make sure your indexes are good.  Also consider using the InnoDB engine instead of MyISAM although there'll be a trade off between the performance lost from using InnoDB against the benefit of getting row-level locking.

The advantages of the *one table vs many tables* are being to do *single* SQL queries such as:

- what's the total size of all of the files in the system:

  `SELECT SUM(size) FROM files`
- show me the top N users by file size (or count):

  `SELECT user, SUM(size) AS total FROM files GROUP BY user ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10`
- show me the last N modified files:

  `SELECT * FROM files ORDER BY mtime DESC LIMIT 10`

All of these are *impossible* to implement efficiently if you have a separate table per user.

Comment: How will you enforce integrity? How will you keep out of the gate duplicates? Read queries are the cheapest you will get. `INNER JOINS` are so much more optimized now days in MySQL that you won't even notice the difference of `0.00001`. What happens if he wants to migrate later on, and so on and so forth... a billion things against this solution.

Comment: @Shef I think everyone got really confused by your initial answer and are now talking at cross purposes.   Please go back and read the question again. I'm proposing a single table for the _file_ records, as opposed to a separate table for each _users_ files.

Comment: @Shef:   First, you may want to dial down the vitriol a little ("a billion things"...seriously!?).  Second, user asked a relatively simple question, and a simple answer was given.  Ord didn't ask for a complete database schema, web stack framework, and hosting solution - just asked about option A vs. B

Comment: Huh ... I can see all of the powerful queries you can perform if you have all the records in one table!

Comment: @Ord: you can do all of those powerful queries with all the records in user and file tables (2 tables, that is) as well; SQL supports subqueries, wherein you create a "table" from a subquery, and then you can gather aggregate statistics from that created table.  It's very useful.

Comment: @Paul you're completely misinterpreting again.  I never said _one_ table for _everything_.  I concisely answered the OPs question about whether a table per user is the right solution. If you go over the comment history again you'll note that it was I that first suggested a single _file_ table **and** a single _user_ table.

Comment: Thank you Alnitak, your solution is very useful. And I did realize that you meant one table _for files_, not one table for everything.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to have multiple tables, because this way you avoid the bottleneck of table locks.

Just to get you started I am giving you three tables:

```
users: user_id(PK) | name | surname | ...

files: file_id(PK) | file_name | file_extension | upload_date | ...

users_files: (user_id | file_id )(PK)
```

*Notice*: `users_files` should have compound primary key made up of both fields.

**3rd party EDIT**: [to clarify, since people may not see all of the comments] many of the comments below were based on the initial answer which only included the first line and was interpreted as meaning a separate table *per user*.

Comment: -1 - this is very bad advice; having a different table for each user is really bad practice.

Comment: @JamWaffles:  I don't see how this is supposedly having a different table for each user.  Each user gets a row in the users table.

Comment: This is the right solution; one entry per user, one entry per file.

Comment: What if I have 1000 users like the OP has. That means 1000 different tables. This is far from ideal, unless I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: @paul for a start you can't parameterise (i.e. bind) the table name in prepared statements.

Comment: @jamwaffles: yes, you're misunderstanding the way databases work.  Each table can hold many records; a table of users holds the records (1000 in this case) for all the users.  I think you're confusing tables and records.  A record is an entry in a table.

Comment: @alnitak: I have no idea what you're talking about with that comment; how is it relevant to anything?

Comment: @JamWaffles: It doesn't mean 1000 different tables, it means 1000 different records, you of all people, supposedly a solution giver, should know the difference.

Comment: @Paul if you don't understand my comment you have no business commenting on this question (or down voting any of the answers).

Comment: @Alnitak: What you are talking about is business logic, which is way off to another layer. You handle that on your programming cores not on the DBMS. However, I don't see how this method, compared to yours, will make it much more difficult for prepared statements.

Comment: OK, so if I understand the proposed solution correctly: _one_ table which contains all file records, _one_ table which includes all user records, and a third table which associates users with files? Is that correct?

Comment: @Shef you seem to have completely changed this answer since it was first posted.  You originally only had the first line which is completely wrong.

Comment: @Shef: You don't create multiple tables to "avoid the bottlenecks of table locks".  You create multiple tables to group related data together.

Comment: @Alnitak: What does a changed answer have to do with the solution it gives? If you are here to troll, keep on...
@Gerret: Yes, you create multiple tables to group related data together, and you create multiple tables to lower the locking bottleneck on table writes, mostly.

Comment: @alnitak: revision history on this post doesn't support your contention that the answer was completely changed; there are two revisions, the original post, and your revision.

Comment: @Shef I'm not trolling.  The OP asked "one table, or one table per user".  You answered "It's best to have multiple tables". Your subsequently added schema then completely changed the meaning of your answer.

Comment: @alnitak: you, with your rep, should understand that frequently, people post incomplete answers on SO to get the earlier timestamp, and then go back and fill in the complete answer; the edits within 5 minutes not getting logged supports that posting paradigm.  Don't ding the answerer for changing the answer to make it correct in a time frame that is reasonable.

Comment: @Paul, from early in the thread, sorry about this, and sorry to the OP too. -(-1) :-)

Comment: @Paul there's a world of difference between incomplete and completely incorrect. Since I realised what Shef had done I've been trying to resolve the issues caused by that inconsistency.

Answer (score 1):

For sure, one large table; MySQL is powerful and efficient and fast and it won't mind a million records. With a single table, you can write more simpler queries to retrieve any data, like:

- what is the total number of files or per user
- what is the total number of files per file type
- what is the average file size
- amount of file size consumed per user

Make sure that your indexes are rightly created, which will depend on the types of queries you intend to run.

Also, if there won't be very frequent writes to your tables, I'd suggest you go for MyISAM storage engine because of its higher performance. However, if contrary, go for InnoDB that supports row-level locking and therefore fewer locking conflicts.

Hope you'll soon experience how fun MySQL is :-)

Answer (score -1):

As per **[Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)** perspective; it';s better to have multiple tables with foreign key contraints...

reference Links:

http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/An-Introduction-to-Database-Normalization/